# Barcode scan from mobile in odoo 10

Tags: barcode, enterprise, odoo-10

How we can implement bar code within odoo so that mobile browsers can read a bar code and odoo captures bar code details.

For example, at first we scan a bar code from mobile, then attach the bar code detail to relevant sales order. After attaching bar code, this sales orders will appears automatically when any user scans that bar code.

We are using enterprise version Odoo 10.x for this purpose.

**Flow:**

> Scan Barcode -> Attach bar code to a sales order -> sales order will
>   be uniquely identified by bar code -> Whenever any user scans bar
>   code, the related sales order opens automatically.

Comment: Is there any module or solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

refer the stock_barcode_mobile module in enterprise package,path /enterprise/stock_barcode_mobile

Comment: Can you add more explanation and details to this answer?